# Remove existing docker containers/images GitLab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I have a GitLab CI pipeline with 3 steps:

- `build`
- `release`
- `deploy`

In my `deploy` step, I; SSH into my DO box, login to GitLab registry, pull down the latest docker image & run it. I am also attempting to remove existing containers/images using:

```bash
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

**`.gitlab.yml`**

```yaml
cache:
  key: "${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} node:latest"
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - build
  - release
  - deploy

build:
  ...

release:
  ...

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: gitlab/dind:latest
  only:
    - master
  environment: production
  when: manual
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "${DEPLOY_SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY}" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -H ${DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - ssh root@${DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP}
      "echo 'CONTAINERS';
      docker ps -aq;
      echo 'IMAGES';
      docker images -q;
      docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq);
      docker rmi $(docker images -q);
      docker login -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} ${CI_REGISTRY};
      docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest;
      docker run -d ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest;"
```

I log out the result of the container/image IDs before I attempt to remove them. The *(partial)* output of that build step is:
[image]

You can see that the `docker ps -aq` command logs out **1** existing container ID & the `docker images -q` logs out **4** existing image IDs. Why then am I getting the error below of:

> "docker rm" requires at least 1 argument

...and...

> "docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument

when I can see that there are existing containers/images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seem like the issue with subshell but You can try with `xargs` if there is an issue with subshell in gitlib.

```
      echo 'IMAGES';
      docker images -q;
      docker ps -aq | xargs docker rm -f;
      docker images -q | xargs docker rmi;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on bash subshell $(...), you would try the

- [`docker container prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/)
- [`docker image prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/)

That would detect stopped/dangling objects and remove them.

Comment: This was a good solution but `prune` only removes stopped containers where at the point of deployment, my previous containers are still running

Answer (score 2):

You are passing all images and container ID's in a different manner to docker rm command.
Try the modifying the script as below.

```
echo 'IMAGES'; 
docker images -q; 
for container in $(docker ps -aq); 
do 
      docker rm -f $container
done

for image in $(docker images -q);
do
      docker rmi $image
done
```

Let us know if you are still facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that removes all listed images but the latest.

```
images=()
images+=($(docker images europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/*/*/*:* -q))
images+=($(docker images trion/ng-cli-karma -q | tail -n +2))
images+=($(docker images aquasec/trivy -q | tail -n +2))
images+=($(docker images bridgecrew/checkov -q | tail -n +2))
if [[ ${images[@]} ]]; then
  echo "removing old images : ${images[@]}"
  docker image rm -f ${images[@]}
else
  echo "no images to remove"
fi
```